# populate dropdown clicking on it

Tags: javascript

I have an empty dropdown like this :

```
<select class="flex-40 sale-select-input">
    <option value="1">-----</option>
select>
```

I want to populate it via ajax request, I used onclick event :

```
let selectInput = document.querySelector('.sale-select-input');
selectInput.addEventListener('click', ()=>{    
  ajax.load('size/get-sizes', this.data(), (result) => {
            this.result = result;
            this.fillSizes()
        }).send();
}
```

ajax result would be something like this :

```
[
  id:1, name:'L',
  id:2, name:'XL'
]
```

and in fillSize :

```
   fillSizes() {

    let selectINput = document.querySelector('.sale-select-input');

    this.result.forEach(size => {
        let option = `<option value="${size.id}">${size.name}</option>`;
        selectINput.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', option);
    });
}
```

but when I click on one of the dropdown options, onclick event fires too. I think i selected wrong event for "ONLY OPENING THE DROPDOWN"
thanks

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with example object returned from the Ajax. Assuming the Ajax works, you can leave that part out since it does not work in the snippet

Comment: If you're set on populating the dropdown on click, maybe just use a `hasBeenPopulated` flag, to keep track of whether it's been populated already. check it before calling ajax, set it after fillsize. EDIT: or better yet, just remove the event listener after you've filled the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You should be populating dropdown on `pageload` and `not on click of dropdown`. Update code like below.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let selectInput = document.querySelector('.sale-select-input');     
    ajax.load('size/get-sizes', this.data(), (result) => {
        this.result = result;
        this.fillSizes()
    }).send();
});
```